# Why file_get_contents return error?

Tags: php, oauth, file-get-contents, yahoo-api

I'm working OAuth connect Yahoo.jp login API

I try sending http request use file_get_contents but **It's return errors**

Here is my code

```
// my apps setting 
    $client_id = 'dj0zaiZpP~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~';
    $appSecret = '129ad~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~';

    // the data to send
    $data = array(
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'redirect_uri' => 'My_redierct_page', 
        'code' => $_GET['code']

    );
    $data = http_build_query($data);

    $header = array(
        "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($client_id . ':' . $appSecret),
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)
    );

    // build your http request
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST', 
            'header' => implode("\r\n", $header),
            'content' => $data, 
            'timeout' => 10
            )
        ));

    // send it
    $resp = file_get_contents('https://auth.login.yahoo.co.jp/yconnect/v1/token', false, $context);
    $json = json_decode($resp);

    echo($json->token_type . " " . $json->access_token);
```

The result...

> file_get_contents(https://auth.login.yahoo.co.jp/yconnect/v1/token): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /var/www/html/api/auth_proc2.php on line 33

Here is another error message get using `set_error_handler()`

> file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I can't understand this situation 
Because I send **Content-type** in http header
and `allow_url_fopen = on` in my php.ini

Please help me~! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other thing I'd suggest using is CURL rather then `file_get_contents` for multiple reasons; first you'll have a lot more control over the request, second its more standard to use curl requests when dealing with API's, and third you'll be able to see better what your problem is.

Try replacing your code with the following and see what you get.

```
$client_id = 'dj0zaiZpP~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~';
$appSecret = '129ad~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~';

$data = array(
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => 'My_redierct_page', 
    'code' => $_GET['code']
);

$curl = curl_init('https://auth.login.yahoo.co.jp/yconnect/v1/token'); 

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $client_id . ':' . $appSecret);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);

print_r($response);
echo '<br /><br />';
print_r($info);

curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume its probably because your using `Content-Type` and not `Content-type` and `Content-Length` instead of `Content-length`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I try change spelling to T->t, and L->l but still  same error